# How can I add pattern constraint on column in already existing table using Sequelize/Postgres

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js, constraints, rdbms

I need to add constraint(regex) on DB level so that no one able to enter/edit that particular column with invalid input on already existing table. I'm using Sequelize, Postgres.

I tried it using migration but still able to enter invalid value in DB. I was expecting that after running below migration I wouldn't able to enter/edit that column with wrong input but not working.
Attaching my code below for you better understanding. Please help me to understand it clearly..

```
`module.exports = {
  async up (queryInterface, Sequelize) {
     await queryInterface.changeColumn('Table', 'Column',{
      type: Sequelize.STRING,
      validate: {
        is: "regex pattern"
      }
    });
  },

  async down (queryInterface, Sequelize) {
     await queryInterface.removeColumn('Table', 'Column');
  }
};`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use **query** directly to add constraints in our migration file. Please find below code for reference that I used in my codebase.

```js
module.exports = {
  async up(queryInterface, Sequelize) {
    await queryInterface.sequelize.query(`
         ALTER TABLE "TableName"
         ADD CONSTRAINT "checkName" CHECK ("column" ~ '^[a-zA-Z0-9]{2}\d{10}$');
 `);
},

async down(queryInterface, Sequelize) {
  await queryInterface.removeConstraint('TableName', 'column');
},
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need here constraints not validation as validation is for used for app side validation and error will be thrown from app side, but constraints are something which throw error from db side. But i think sequelize does not provide complex constraints so that after migration it will apply to column.
you can check doc here for more reference -> https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/core-concepts/validations-and-constraints/

Comment: You are right I need to add constraint. Now question becomes how can I add constraint for regex pattern? Is this possible with migration or there is other way?

Comment: thanks I edited my question with right word constraint not validation

Comment: @AnjuRawat there is limitation with below code it defies the purpose of ORM framework, not every db engine support same query style